# playframe work can't find the right route

Tags: java, scala, playframework

I have a strange problem

this is what I have in `routes` files

```
GET     /path/list                          controllers.path.getPaths()
GET     /path/:id                           controllers.path.get(id:Int)
```

when I try to go `<domain>/path/list`  the following error shows up:

> For request 'GET /path/list' [Cannot parse parameter id as Int: For
>   input string: "list"]

I also tried to change the order in `routes` file

```
GET     /path/:id                           controllers.path.get(id:Int)
GET     /path/list                          controllers.path.getPaths()
```

I still get the same error. so my question is

1. isn't route supposed to match the first path that matches?
2. what else could be the problem (e.g. java codes)?

Comment: I am guessing your paths are ambiguous, you should have like `/path/list` and `/path/:id`

Comment: Add the complete routes file, please.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From the code you've provided this should work. The routes are not ambiguous because (from Play documentation):

> Many routes can match the same request. If there is a conflict, the first route (in declaration order) is used.

if your `routes` ordering looks like this:

```
GET     /path/list                          controllers.path.getPaths()
GET     /path/:id                           controllers.path.get(id:Int)
```

`/path/list` will match before attempting to extract/transform the id parameter `id:Int` from the path and throwing.

> If you want Play to transform the incoming parameter into a specific Scala type, you can add an explicit type

The only way this would **not** work is if you attempted to visit a route that did not match `list` or was not an `Int`:

```
For request 'GET /path/lists' [Cannot parse parameter id as Int: For input string: "lists"]
```

Comment: yes mate, u were right assuming it should work. I created a new project and put all the files into it and it started working. I'm happy that it worked but I nearly smashed my monitor for spending hours for something stupid...